# Re-use Hazelcast serialization logic in a MapStore implementation

Tags: hazelcast

I have implemented a custom serializer for my POJOs using `IdentifiedDataSerializable` so that I can maintain a fine-grained control as classes evolve and new fields need to be added/removed. For some collections I also need persistency and have implemented a `MapStore` using an embedded key-value store. My problem is that I would like to re-use the `IdentifiedDataSerializable` serialization in the `MapStore` implementation, to leverage on code re-use as well as to ensure class evolution in the future.

I have tried to obtain a reference to the internal Hazelcast `SerializationService`, but it's not readily available via the "public" APIs in `HazelcastInstance`. In fact I was unable to figure out any decent way of getting hold of it.

What I would in fact like is a version of the `MapStore` interface which works on byte array level where Hazelcast handles the serialization/deserialization before invocation. New feature request I guess...

Any ideas how to solve this in the meanwhile are welcome.

Answer (score 3):

Breaking your question into two parts:

1. How to avoid having to maintain different serialization behaviors
   for Hazelcast and a persistent store.
2. How to avoid the overhead of an extra serialization-deserialization
   step when going between the Hazelcast machinery and the persistence
   machinery.

### For the first part:

I've had great results using [Jackson](https://github.com/FasterXML/jackson) both for Hazelcast serialization and for persistence of the sort needed to implement a `MapStore`. This allows me to use the same serialization logic consistently, without having to worry about different semantics for different settings.

[Fuad Malikov's blog entry](http://hazelcast.org/comparing-hazelcast-3-serialization-methods-with-kryo-serialization/) comparing various kinds of Hazelcast serialization has an example of how to use Jackson binary serialization. You can use the same logic in your `MapStore` implementation. Even better, you can use a different `ObjectMapper` for the latter that writes JSON instead of the binary Smile format -- the serialization semantics are otherwise identical, but the binary format is more compact and faster to read and write, which is what you want for Hazelcast. I've found it very useful to be able to persist human-readable data in the persistent store, for which I'm less concerned about space and time efficiency and more concerned about maintainability. (I've actually been able to "patch" data in production by editing the raw JSON, not something I would ever consider doing with a binary format!)

Jackson is very flexible when it comes to adding and removing fields, thanks to its `@JsonAnyGetter` and `@JsonAnySetter` annotations, which allow you to handle unrecognized fields gracefully.

There's also the ability to "inject" serialization behavior into classes over which you don't have control.

### For the second part:

As you've noticed, Hazelcast doesn't support a `MapStore` variant that works exclusively in terms of the serialized form, so each load involves a deserialization followed by a serialization to the Hazelcast structure. From my experience and reading, highly optimized serialization libraries like Jackson and [Kryo](https://code.google.com/p/kryo/) are so fast that the extra work is entirely dominated by the cost of reading from the persistent store.

If it's important enough to you to avoid that extra step, you could 
use [MapInterceptors](http://www.hazelcast.org/docs/latest/manual/html/mapinterceptor.html) on a `IMap<String, byte[]>` to perform the deserialization in `interceptGet` and serialization in `interceptPut`. I don't recommend it, though, because you're then stuck with recreating functionality that Hazelcast provides out of the box.

Comment: Hi Tim,
Thanks for the good suggestion. I guess if one does not use Portable (which speeds up Hazelcast queries by not requiring full deserialization) it does not so much matter which serialization is used as long as speed & size are reasonable. I did not really follow your suggestion about wrapping the IMap interface, can you expand?

Comment: I expanded a little and added a pointer to the new MapInterceptors feature. I don't really want to flesh this out much further because I think it's a really bad idea. You'd only want to turn to it if you had good measurements that showed that the extra serialization step was really hurting performance, and I have a lot of trouble believing that would ever be the case in practice.

Comment: Agreed. Thanks. A JSON/Kryo approach seems like the best workaround for now. I do hope the Hazelcast guys will consider to add a direct MapStore interface with pre-serialized key/values.

Comment: I added a feature request for the Hazelcast dev team [1975](https://github.com/hazelcast/hazelcast/issues/1975).